# different output for model name with capital letter in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I dont understand how I get a different output for lesson_date field if in the select I use Lessons.lesson_date' or lessons.lesson_date. I thought I am supposed to use Lessons and not lessons and that the for a single name it doesnt really matter.

with Lessons.lesson_date I get on the debug :

```
'lesson_date' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {
        'time' => '2015-07-09T00:00:00+00:00',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
```

with lessons.lesson_date I get a better output:

```
'lessons' => [
        'id' => '5399',
        'lesson_date' => '2015-07-09'
```

//this is the code below I am talking about. The Lessons.lesson_date gives a different output than if I change this to lessons.lesson_date

```
 $query3 = $this->Lessons->find()
              ->contain(['TutoringTypes'])
              ->select(['lessons.id','Lessons.lesson_date','Lessons.tutoring_type_id',
                  'TutoringTypes.value'])      
               ->where(['Lessons.lesson_date >' => $a3,'Lessons.lesson_date <' => $a4, .....
```

Comment: my question is why do i get different output when i capitalize the lesson table name? I thought the correct method was to capitalize the table name reference

Comment: where exactly  you use `lessons` instead of `Lessons`?

Comment: I am really unclear about these responses. Please be more specific about what you dont understand 
   
 
'where exactly you use lessons instead of Lessons'- this doesnt mean anything? Look at the code I provided as you see query3. It has a capital L for Lessons.lesson_date and gives a different output than lessons.lesson_date

Answer (score 2):

That is the expected/correct behavior when following the conventions, the date gets casted according to its type.

The latter output might be better suited for what you are doing with the data, but generally the former is "better" since a date object gives you more freedom of manipulating dates, handling localization, output formatting, etc...

### Why?

As to the why, the output is different because the ORM will not cast the value in case of a non-conventional column alias, as it's not present in the type map that holds the information about which column is of which type.

Using `lessons.lesson_date` will create an alias of

```
lessons__lesson_date
```

which is not following the conventions, where as using `Lessons.lesson_date` will create an alias of

```
Lessons__lesson_date
```

which does follow the conventions, and will match the field in the type map, causing the ORM to cast the data.

### Changing the behavior

If you need `YYYY-MM-DD` output, then you could simply output it formatted it in your view like

```
echo $lesson->lesson_date->i18nFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

or change the default output format (which is used when the date gets casted to a string)

```
\Cake\I18n\FrozenDate::setToStringFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

or maybe even change the type in the type map in order to keep the date string as is

```
    $query = $this->Lessons
        ->find()
        // ...

    $types = ['Lessons__lesson_date' => 'string'] + $query->selectTypeMap()->defaults();
    $query->selectTypeMap()->defaults($types);
```

### See also

- **[Cookbook > Date & Time > Formatting](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#formatting)**
- **[Cookbook > Date & Time > Setting the Default Locale and Format String](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#setting-the-default-locale-and-format-string)**
- **[\Cake\ORM\Query::_addDefaultSelectTypes()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.ORM.Query.html#__addDefaultSelectTypes)**
- **[\Cake\Database\Query::selectTypeMap()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_selectTypeMap)**
- **[\Cake\Database\Query::typeMap()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Database.TypeMapTrait.html#_typeMap)**